# Boot HTC Desire S into recovery mode without power button

Tags: recovery-mode

Hi Android Enthusiasts,

The power button of my HTC Desire S is broken (no response whatsoever), so I have to connect my phone to a usb cable to get it out of stand-by mode. I understood that with a custom rom I can use a volume button for instance to get it out of stand-by mode. However, for flashing the rom onto the HTC Desire S I have to boot it into recovery mode. Which involves pressing the power button...
Any alternative ways to boot the phone into recovery mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes:

1. Make sure ADB is installed on your PC (see e.g. [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575))
2. Make sure you have *USB debugging* enabled (*Settings → Development*)
3. Connect your device to the PC via USB
4. On the PC, open a command prompt and type `adb reboot recovery`

Your device should now reboot into recovery mode.

Answer (score 0):

If your device is rooted then you can download an application called Quick Boot from the Google play store.

Check this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.siriusapplications.quickboot

This app will let you quickly boot your device in various modes (including Recovery).

Thanks